# Element removed from stack view when switching orientations

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode7.3

I am using size classes and setting a button to not be installed in compact width (via interface builder).

[image: IB Screenshot]

This works fine except when the device rotates and goes from compact width to regular width. The button in question then appears in the top left corner of the screen instead of in the stack view where it normally appears for regular width. If the device (iPhone 6s Plus) starts out in the landscape orientation, the element appears correctly in the stack view and then is correctly hidden when switched to vertical. If the device starts out in vertical orientation and then switched to horizontal (so regular width), the button is removed from the stack view and ends up in the upper left corner.

Here is the correct layout for regular and compact width:
[image: Screenshot regular width]
[image: Screenshot compact width]

Now, after switching from vertical orientation (compact) to horizontal (regular), the button is still gone...

[image: Screenshot button gone from regular width]

...And when the botton panel slides down, you can see the button is in the top left.

[image: Screenshot button appears in top left]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here’s how I fixed it: Basically, I had layout issues when the button was installed for compact width. I fixed those layout issues, and then again set it to be uninstalled for compact width and now it works as expected.